# Nuxt: is it possible to just prerender just one route at a time?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, prerender

`generate` tried to prerender the entire site (including dynamic routes if they are specified).  I'm wondering if it is possible to have some sort of hook (say when a user's profile changes) that would re-prerender just that one page.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?